# Multivariable Taylor Expansion about a function and it's derivative

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose I have a function $f(r,a,b,b')$. $a$ and $b$ are both functions of $r$, and $b'=\frac{\partial b}{\partial r}$. I want to make a Taylor expansion about $a\approx 0$ and $b\approx 0$ (because $a$ and $b$ are both small, I expect $b'$ to be small as well).

If the function was $f(r,a,b)$ only, I would be able to use the regular Taylor expansion for multiple variables.
\begin{equation}
f(r,a,b)\approx f(r,0,0)+\frac{\partial f (r,0,0)}{\partial a}a + \frac{\partial f (r,0,0)}{\partial b}b + ....
\end{equation}

Should I treat $b'$ as though it were it's own variable (even though it has an obvious relation to the other variables of f? 
\begin{equation}
f(r,a,b,b')\approx f(r,0,0,0)+\frac{\partial f (r,0,0,0)}{\partial a}a + \frac{\partial f (r,0,0,0)}{\partial b}b + + \frac{\partial f (r,0,0,0)}{\partial b}b' +....
\end{equation}

I'm a bit worried that I am somehow 'double counting' by having two things related to the function b.

Comment: Why does $a,b\approx 0$ imply $b'\approx 0$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ must always be small (e.g. at all $r$). If $b'$ is not small, then the condition that $b\approx 0$ would be violated.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't see the argument. For example, $x \sin(1/x) \approx 0$ near $x=0$, but its derivative goes haywire.

Comment: I will need to think a better justification for how to treat b' then. (Thanks for pointing out the counterexample). If it matters, my actual function that I'm trying to expand is $G(r,a,b,b')=\frac{(1+a)(b+b^2+rb')}{(1+b)^2r^2}$.